# Zend Framework Modular application?

Tags: api, zend-framework, module

I am new to Zend Modular Application . I have an api controller and I want to call other modules from this controller. For example post the data to this address:

```
http://localhost/api/addTask
```

I added a custom route to redirect all of requests to api/index
For now, How can I call a module or another method by the indexAction?
for example:

```
function indexAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequets()->getParams();
    $controller = $params[0];//I know that there is issues with this line but keep going...
    //module name is addTask

    //call to module or controller addTask
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This would be much easier to accomplish in ZF 2.0.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_forward()` to call other actions from a controller
`_forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null):`
Here is the link to ZF manual [Zend Action Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods)